# Warning: odbc_fetch_row(): 37 is not a valid ODBC result resource

Tags: php

Whats wrong in my code, when I test it the output goes write but in my browser shows the warning that say's "Warning: odbc_fetch_row(): 37 is not a valid ODBC result resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\webinterface\requests.php on line 729"

I don't know what does it mean, the sql statement result just goes fine in dbexplorer. 
by the way may database is paradox and using odbc to connect my php to paradox.

Does anyone can help me? Thanks you very much

my code hereunder:

```
    $connectionstring = odbc_connect(DB_DNS,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
        $auditRequestNo     = "";
        $ar_requestno   = "";
        $svemp1 = "";
        $svemp2 = "";               
        foreach($uArr as $arNo){                
            $ar_requestno .= (!empty($ar_requestno))? ",".$arNo : $arNo;
            $auditRequestNo   .= (!empty($auditRequestNo))? ",".sprintf("%08d", $arNo) : sprintf("%08d", $arNo);
        }

        $query = "SELECT SV_EmployeeNo,Sv_EmployeeNo2 \r\n".
                        "FROM AuthorizationRequests \r\n".
                        "WHERE ARNO IN (".$ar_requestno.") ";   
        $result = odbc_do($connectionstring, $query);
        while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
            $svemp1 = odbc_result($result,1);
            $svemp2 = odbc_result($result,2);
            switch(intval($s)){         
                case 1: // approved 
                        if(empty($svemp1) and empty($svemp2)){
                            $update_fields = "flag=0, DateApproved = { d '".date('Y-m-d')."' } , SV_EmployeeNo=".$_SESSION['uen']." ";
                            $update_query =   "UPDATE AuthorizationRequests \r\n".
                                              "SET ".$update_fields."\r\n ".
                                              "WHERE ArNo IN(".$ar_requestno.")";
                            $update_query = odbc_exec($connectionstring, $update_query);
                            odbc_close($connectionstring);                              
                        }else if(!empty($svemp1) and empty($svemp2) and $svemp1 != $_SESSION['uen']){
                            $update_fields = "flag=".$s.", DateApproved2 = { d '".date('Y-m-d')."' } , SV_EmployeeNo2=".$_SESSION['uen']." ";                            
                            $update_query =   "UPDATE AuthorizationRequests \r\n".
                                              "SET ".$update_fields."\r\n ".
                                              "WHERE ArNo IN(".$ar_requestno.")";
                            $update_query = odbc_exec($connectionstring, $update_query);
                            odbc_close($connectionstring); 
                        }
                    #}                
                    break;
                case 2: // rejected
                        $update_fields = "flag=".$s.", DateApproved = { d '".date('Y-m-d')."' }, SV_EmployeeNo=".$_SESSION['uen']." ";
                        $update_query =   "UPDATE AuthorizationRequests \r\n".
                                          "SET ".$update_fields."\r\n ".
                                          "WHERE ArNo IN(".$ar_requestno.")";
                        $update_query = odbc_exec($connectionstring, $update_query);
                        odbc_close($connectionstring); 
                    break;
                default: // reset
                        $update_fields = "flag=0, DateApproved=NULL, SV_EmployeeNo=NULL, DateApproved2=NULL, SV_EmployeeNo2=NULL";
                        $update_query =   "UPDATE AuthorizationRequests \r\n".
                                          "SET ".$update_fields."\r\n ".
                                          "WHERE ArNo IN(".$ar_requestno.")";
                        $update_query = odbc_exec($connectionstring, $update_query);
                        odbc_close($connectionstring); 
                    break;
            }   
        }
```

Comment: Just a guess here but I'd lose the `\r\n` characters in the query string

Comment: SQL works fine, I already check the output in txt file and test on the database explorer.

Answer (score 1):

use if condition

```
 $result = odbc_do($connectionstring, $query);

if($result)
{

        while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){

         }
}
```

Comment: Still I'm getting the same warning.

Comment: then use @ or while($row = odbc_fetch_row($result)){

Comment: I get rid of the warning message by editing the php.ini removing E_ALL in error_reporting I have not test the @. what does @ means?

Comment: Pradeep Singh your right, I don't have to edit my php.ini property error_reporting. Thanks a lot.